# Is it impossible to get the gold medal in Duke Landwalker scenario?

Tags: archipelago-solo-exp

The solo rules say you must play with the 4-player action wheel and this means that I'm limited to 3 explorations per turn.

Consider now the Duke Landwalker scenario that ends when you explore all the 24 regions available in the game. In it you only get the gold medal if you have **less than** 8 evolution and character cards. Remember that you must buy one of those cards per turn.

Now observe that if I can explore up to 3 times per turn, it'll take me at least 8 turns to end the game, rendering the gold medal unachievable.

This seem very weird to me. Am I right? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scout card is key to this.  It allows you to do an extra exploration which makes it doable in under 8 turns.

Comment: Indeed, but don't you think that's weird? You must be lotery lucky to be able to complete a scenario? I think there is another card that could also help. Still it's all about luck. Is that what this scenario is about? Being incredibly lucky?

Comment: Quite a few of them do require a particular card in the first 5 to stand a chance at silver or gold.  The developer suggests a variant where you chose the starting 5, so the puzzle becomes figuring out which they key cards are for that scenario.

Comment: Could you please point to the source where this variant was proposed?

Comment: It was suggested by the designer in this thread http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/926230/has-anyone-achieved-first-place-solo-scenario