# What should you do if the surplus worker level limit is exceeded?

Tags: archipelago

What happens if, after exploring, you have to increase the surplus workers level beyond the board limit (level 26)? Should you increase the rebelion marker by the same amount that exceeded the surplus workers level? Make the exploration fail? Do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion given by user @Oltarus, I contacted Ludically and got the following answer from Christophe Boelinger, the designer:

> Do nothing.
>
> When The surplus worker reaches the max level then it stays there no matter if any effect would require to go higher, and in such a case nothing else happens than leaving the marker at the max level. Which is already not a very helping situation anyway.
>   And this no matter if it is in a solo game or multi player game.

Answer (score 0):

The rules don't specify what's going on in that case because it's highly unprobable that it happens. If it happened to you:

- Are you sure you got all the rules right?
- Has it happened more than once or was it just a bad luck?

You may want to ask the game designer about that issue if you think it will happen again. You can contact him through his **[Contact page](http://archipelago.ludically.com/contact)**. Please let us know if he answers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I reached this situation during a solo game (btw, [check this out](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18307/is-it-impossible-to-get-the-gold-medal-in-duke-landwalker-scenario)). I am confident that I got the rules right, and I agree it seems unusual for that to happen in a multiplayer match, but in a solo game (in particular in the Duke Landwalker scenario), it seems highly likely for that to happen.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the solo expansion and can't answer your other question. Good luck for your searching!